# I have a checkbox and an information icon.If checkbox is checked ,than i have to show some message on the tooltip of that information icon

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a checkbox and an information icon.If checkbox is checked ,than i have to show some message on the tooltip of that information icon.and if checkbox is unchecked than i have to show a different message on the tooltip of that information icon.

Comment: $(".checkboxContainer").hover()----I have used this .But it is not working

Comment: You need to show your html for the checkbox and icon

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Html Code:

```
<input type=”checkbox” name=”chkInput” id=”chkInput” value=”Show Information” />Show Information
<img id=”imgInformation” src=”info.jpg” alt=”Information” height=”50” width="50" tooltip=”Information Checkbox Unchecked”>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(“#chkInput”).change(function(){
  if(this.checked){
   $(“#imgInformation").tooltip({ content: “Information Checkbox Checked” });
  }
else{
    $(“#imgInformation").tooltip({ content: “Information Checkbox Unchecked” });
  }
});
```

See the working fiddle for setting tooltip using jquery http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/vvVwD/.
Jquery 1.9.1 and JqueryUI 1.9.2 are included.